# Extra blank page on print

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an image to print on a web form. The image control loads the image dynamically at runtime. There is a print button on the page which gives me print to pdf option. The pdf which gets created generates an extra page along with the image to print

The size of the image is 649*602 in px.

the javascript code for print is as follows

```
 function printDiv(divName) {
            var title = document.title;
            document.title = '';
            var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;

            var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

            document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
            window.print();

            document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
            document.title = title;
            return false;
        }
```

The aspx page contains the following

```
<body style="background: none; padding-top: 8%; padding-left: 2%;">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="float: left; padding: 1%; width: 55%;" id="divInstructions">
        <asp:Image ID="imgInstructionSheet" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left: 3%; float: left;">
        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgBtnPrint" SkinID="Print" OnClientClick="return printDiv('divInstructions')"
            ToolTip="Print" />

            <%-- <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgBtnPrint" SkinID="Print" OnClientClick="return window.print();"
            ToolTip="Print" />--%>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper" style="float: left; width: 36%; padding-top: 1%;">
        <a href="#" class="instrulink" style="padding-left: 2%" onmouseover="DisplayInstruction();" onmouseout="RemoveInstruction();">Display Instructions</a>
        <div style="display: none; padding-top: 8%; margin-left: -8%; float: left; overflow: hidden;"
            id="printinstruction">
            <table style="background-color: lightgray; padding: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -khtml-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="../Images/PageSetUp.jpg" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            <b style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:14px;"><u>For Proper Printout Follow The Instructions:</u></b>
                            <br />
                            <li class="cssLi">Click on File Menu Goto Page Setup.</li>
                            <li class="cssLi">In Page Setup Dialog Box.</li>
                            <li class="cssLi">Set Paper Size To Letter (8.5x11").</li>
                            <li class="cssLi">Set Left Margin as 0.5 and Right Margin as 0.5.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Is there any way I can eliminate the extra blank page?
I tried reducing the image size but no effect.

the rendered html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
    Instruction Sheet
</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Javascript/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        a:hover + div#printinstruction
        {
            visibility: visible;
        }
        .cssLi
        {
        position: relative;
        left: 16px;
        font-family: verdana;
        font-size: 14px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function HideFromAnchor() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#printinstruction').slideUp();
            }, 1000);
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('a.instrulink').mouseover(function () {
                $('#printinstruction').slideDown();
                $('#printinstruction').css('margin-top', '26px')
                $('#printinstruction').css('width', '395px');
                $('#printinstruction').css('height', '510px');
            });

            $('div.wrapper').mouseleave(function () {
                $('#printinstruction').slideUp();
            });

        });


        function DisplayInstruction() {
            $('#printinstruction').slideDown();
            $('#printinstruction').css('margin-top', '26px')
            $('#printinstruction').css('width', '395px');
            $('#printinstruction').css('height', '510px');
        }

        function RemoveInstruction() {
            $('#printinstruction').slideUp();
        }

        function printDiv(divName) {
            var title = document.title;
            document.title = '';
            var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;

            var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

            document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
            window.print();

            document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
            document.title = title;
            return false;
        }
    </script>
<link href="../App_Themes/default/1.9.1-jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/default/Default.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/default/form-field-tooltip.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/default/InquiryStyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/default/iqbackoffice.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/default/IQGLInputControl.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/default/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/default/jquerydcss.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><link href="../App_Themes/default/popup.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /></head>
<body style="background: none; padding-top: 8%; padding-left: 2%;">
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="InstructionsSheet.aspx?CompanyId=evh&amp;CheckRequestType=CHECKREQUESTFAX" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2MjQwOTYzMTgPZBYCAgMPZBYCAgEPDxYCHghJbWFnZVVybAUqQ2hlY2tSZXF1ZXN0SW1hZ2UvQ2hlY2tSZXF1ZXN0SW5zdF92ZWcuanBnZGQYAQUeX19Db250cm9sc1JlcXVpcmVQb3N0QmFja0tleV9fFgEFC2ltZ0J0blByaW50Ibf/odbg0lrXs/vlUgzr3pUnWxPgOvUSkGEiBBhsVNk=" />
</div>

<div>

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdAAIycRPb8aWzu8amhADzp9D7vxA7O73wp6e8dR9A7rKNQ6U+XW+JbgNalutolAAvvabl2zSBHocsK8wmZxrQUUtL" />
</div>
    <div style="float: left; padding: 1%; width: 55%;" id="divInstructions">
        <img id="imgInstructionSheet" src="CheckRequestImage/CheckRequestInst_veg.jpg" style="border-width:0px;" />
    </div>
    <div style="padding-left: 3%; float: left;">
        <input type="image" name="imgBtnPrint" id="imgBtnPrint" title="Print" class="Buttons" onmouseout="this.src=window.location.protocol + &#39;//&#39; + window.location.host + &#39;/&#39; + &#39;ClientWeb/Images/Print_over.png&#39;;" onmouseover="this.src=window.location.protocol + &#39;//&#39; + window.location.host + &#39;/&#39; + &#39;ClientWeb/Images/Print_on.png&#39;;" onfocus="this.src=window.location.protocol + &#39;//&#39; + window.location.host + &#39;/&#39; + &#39;ClientWeb/Images/Print_on.png&#39;;" onblur="this.src=window.location.protocol + &#39;//&#39; + window.location.host + &#39;/&#39; + &#39;ClientWeb/Images/Print_over.png&#39;;" src="../Images/Print_over.png" alt="Print" onclick="return printDiv(&#39;divInstructions&#39;);" style="border-width:0px;" />


    </div>
    <div class="wrapper" style="float: left; width: 36%; padding-top: 1%;">
        <a href="#" class="instrulink" style="padding-left: 2%" onmouseover="DisplayInstruction();" onmouseout="RemoveInstruction();">Display Instructions</a>
        <div style="display: none; padding-top: 8%; margin-left: -8%; float: left; overflow: hidden;"
            id="printinstruction">
            <table style="background-color: lightgray; padding: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -khtml-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="../Images/PageSetUp.jpg" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            <b style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:14px;"><u>For Proper Printout Follow The Instructions:</u></b>
                            <br />
                            <li class="cssLi">Click on File Menu Goto Page Setup.</li>
                            <li class="cssLi">In Page Setup Dialog Box.</li>
                            <li class="cssLi">Set Paper Size To Letter (8.5x11").</li>
                            <li class="cssLi">Set Left Margin as 0.5 and Right Margin as 0.5.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the rendered html?

Comment: Use css media `print` instead of javascript.

Comment: @Ygor Cardoso- I have posted the rendered HTML